# Htaccess Redirects with Parameters (need to be removded)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For an migration of a new website i need to redirect /example.html?id=2 redirected to /example/new-page.html

When i create an redirect like this:

> Redirect 301 /example.html?id=2 https://www.url.com/example/new-page.html
>   Redirect 301 /example2.html?bla=34 https://www.url.com/example/new-page2.html
>   Redirect 301 /eteste.html?yolo=2 https://www.url.com/example/new-page3.html

It returned into this:

> https://www.url.com/example/new-page.html?id=2
>   etc

Change it into this doesn't work either:

> Redirect 301 /example.html?id=2 https://www.url.com/example/new-page.html?

Is there something i'm doing wrong (yes! ;))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite to match against the query string :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^example.html$ https://www.url.com/example/new-page.html? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: There isn't a special query string, i did edit the question a bit. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted?